# Sitemap control in SP 2010

Tags: 2010, development, visual-studio

Does SP have sitemap control (or web part or ...) which can be inserted (or turned ON) in some custom web? I would like that people have oportunity to navigate site with that and not just quick launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution which is "out of the box" and enough customizable (at least by my opinion)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPSiteMapWebPart.aspx

I assume that this should be enough for most of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

SPTreeView and SPHierarchyDataSourceControl

Comment: Can you please provide some link / example ?!

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897657.aspx

Comment: I think that I found better and more out of the box solution, but however thank you for link!